# Regarding Alternatives To OpenCL Support

Tags: gpu, opencl

Proud user for over 10 years--

I recently attempted to upgrade from 2.93 to 3.2 and realized openCL support is no longer offered for Cycles.
I'm using an Acer Nitro AN515-43 Laptop which is about 3 years old with AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx, and a Radeon RX 560X series display adapter.
I am not an expert on GPUs or display, but I'd like to be able to use my GPU for Cycles renders.
Does the Blender Foundation or AMD have any plans to make my processor(s) compatible with Cycles in the future? Again, please excuse my ignorance of these things.
Thanks,
Kenn Toomey